# Where to close the SQLiteOpenHelper if i am using a singelton one

Tags: android

i have the following class that permit user to get a `SQLiteOpenHelper` object

```
import android.content.Context;

public class DBUtils {  

    private DBUtils(){

    }


    private static DBHelper dbHelper ;


    public static synchronized DBHelper getDBHelper(Context context){

        if(dbHelper == null){
            dbHelper = new DBHelper(context, ApplicationMetaData.DATABASE_NAME, null, ApplicationMetaData.DATABASE_VERSION);
        }
        return dbHelper;


    }



    public static synchronized void closeDBHelper(){

        if(dbHelper!=null )
            dbHelper.close();
        dbHelper = null;
    }


    @Override
    protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        throw new CloneNotSupportedException();
    }

}
```

i want to know where should i `close` this singleton object i can't relay on the `onTerminate()` method since it will not be called . i want to close it when the user exit my app ? any solution for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As there is no such "app is closed" event in Android by design. You either have to handle you database connection per `Activity` so you will know when you `Activity` gets destroyed or you have to somehow take care about which object uses the database helper and only close the helper when no other object is using the helper any more.

If you stay with the singleton solution be aware to pass an `Application` context to the `getDBHelper()` method and not a `Activity` context as this might lead to memory leaks.

Comment: Or, in the constructor of getDBHelper() always call `context.getApplicationContext()` - this is safer than relying on always passing the application context. Also, with the singleton pattern you typically don't ever close your SQLiteOpenHelper, just as you don't close it when writing a ContentProvider.

Comment: sure i pass the Application Context to the getDBHelper() , you mean that i should close the helper if no one is using it by calling close ?  nice idea , what about make reference counter in the DBHelper is every one call getDBHelper() i will increment that counter and every one close i decrement it by one and check if its zero call close

Comment: Yes a reference counter will do the job.

Comment: If you do use a reference counter, you might want to rename your `getDBHelper` to `openDBHelper`. It will be clearer that each `open` needs to be paired with a `close`.

Answer (score 7):

Don't worry about closing it.  Just make sure you never create more than one SQLiteOpenHelper.  See here:

http://touchlabblog.tumblr.com/post/24474750219/single-sqlite-connection

Comment: I've been having this battle for years, but again, you don't need to close your db connection.  Summary and evidence: http://kpgalligan.tumblr.com/post/109546839958/single-database-connection

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using an `AtomicInteger` to track the count of the `getDBHelper` calls. Then you could call `getDBHelper` in each `Activity` and close at `onPause`/`onDestroy` (whatever suits you case). Each close call decrements the counter and if the counter is at `0` you could really close your helper. For example see this [sample code](http://ormlite.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/ormlite/examples/android/HelloAndroidTwoDbs/src/com/example/hellotwodbs/DatabaseHelper1.java?revision=2538&view=markup) from ORMlite which demonstrates this approach.