# What does this error message mean ? - sqlite3_exec - Failed to set synchronous mode = 1(Normal)

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am trying to open a SQLiteDatabase in a `"Service"` which fails with the following exception:

```
10-21 19:33:23.547: E/SqliteDatabaseCpp(31208): sqlite3_exec - Failed to set synchronous mode = 1(Normal) 
10-21 19:33:23.547: E/SQLiteDatabase(31208): Failed to open the database. closing it.
10-21 19:33:23.547: E/SQLiteDatabase(31208): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseLockedException: database is locked
10-21 19:33:23.547: E/SQLiteDatabase(31208):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.dbopen(Native Method)
10-21 19:33:23.547: E/SQLiteDatabase(31208):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:1135)
10-21 19:33:23.547: E/SQLiteDatabase(31208):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:1086)
10-21 19:33:23.547: E/SQLiteDatabase(31208):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:1173)
10-21 19:33:23.547: E/SQLiteDatabase(31208):    at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:858)
10-21 19:33:23.547: E/SQLiteDatabase(31208):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:228)
10-21 19:33:23.547: E/SQLiteDatabase(31208):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:157)
```

Can somebody please explain what this means? and how can it be fixed?. The database is opened in the `MainActivity` and a `Service`.

Comment: It is Writable. There is some data going into the Database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is an access conflict happened when the db was used (locked) by one thread (the activity?), the other thread (the service?) tried to use (lock) it but failed.

You can make your own SQLiteOpenHelper a singleton class, and then share it between the activity and service, and then the class will handle the conflict properly for you. See [the discussion in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10371233/where-to-close-the-sqliteopenhelper-if-i-am-using-a-singelton-one)

Answer (score 0):

Check if the database is opened by other thread but not closed when you try to open it again. If yes, just try to close it after use.